# DataTables responsive issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, responsive

I'm trying to use DataTables.js on a few pages and I need to make them responsive. Multiple tables on a few different pages work great, but on one page the columns and width always end up sticking out of the container.

When I reduce the screen, the last column (action column) gets hidden, but when I reduce the screen further, it just stays that way and the table stretches out the container despite the width and maxwidth css properties.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped no-footer dt-responsive" data-order='[[ 4, "asc" ]]'>
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Threee</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
      <th data-orderable="false">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="(picture_url)" alt="" />
        <span>Some Small text</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        Value
      </td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> Value</td>
      <td data-sort="(sort value)"><span class="label label-info">Value</span></td>
      <td>
        <a href="(action_url)" title="Title" type="button"
          class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><span><i class="fa fa-view"></i> Details</span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the initialisation js code:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "No information is available at this time."
    }
});
```

I use this on a window resize (debounce):

```
table.responsive.recalc();
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Comment: Have you checked out this page https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/ ?

Comment: This is also worth a quick squint: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/